# How do I migrate several tables of data into a single table with new logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have several tables. Lets call them:

1. ProductsFavorite ( ProductID, BusinessID, UserID )
2. ServicesFavorite ( ServiceID, BusinessID, UserID )
3. BusinessesFavorite ( BusinessID, UserID )

Previously, a user could add a business page to their favorites. They could also add individual products to their favorites, and services. I've stored these in separate tables.

Since then, I've changed the dynamics of the site, and these are all just called "likes". I now have a new table:

Table: Likes

1. UniqueID
2. BusinessID
3. UserID
4. Type

UniqueID is the primary key of the item, ( I.e. Business, Service, or Product )
BusinessID is the primary key of the business, from the business table.
UserID is the primary key of the user from the users table.
Type is a varchar, ( I.e. Business, Product, Service )

What I need to do is copy the old data into the new table, but not sure how. I also need to do so if it doesn't exist. So here would be a simple example of what I want to achieve:

So lets say I have the following in the ProductsFavorite table:

```
FavoriteID     ProductID     BusinessID     UserID
------------|-------------|--------------|---------
1            10            230            5
2            13            135            7
3            6             300            5
```

I want to insert migrate, or copy these into the new Likes table, but only if that person hasn't liked the product with the new system already. Example:

```
UniqueID       BusinessID    Type           UserID
------------|--------------|-------------|---------
10           230            Product       5
13           135            Product       7
6            300            Product       5
```

I'm not sure of the best way to manage this, and also need to be sure that there isn't a "double" in there. New system has been live for a couple days so some people may have "liked" something they've previously "added to favorites."

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, Management Studio, etc.

Thank you for your help!

========== EDIT ===========

I'm making some progress on this using a test table.

```
INSERT INTO Like_Test (
 UniqueID
,BusinessID
,UserID
,Type
,Date_Created
) 

SELECT
 a.ProductID
,a.BusinessID
,a.UserID
,'Product'
,a.Date_Created

FROM ProductFav a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Like_Test b WHERE b.UniqueID = a.ProductID AND b.UserID = a.UserID AND b.ElementType = 'Product')
```

If I delete the top 1 entry from the Like_Test table, running the above query should insert a single record. Well, I say it should but obviously I'm doing something wrong. So the WHERE clause on this insert doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add image of data schema in your question to make it more clear?

Comment: I've made a bit of progress. Please see my latest edit. Thank you :)

Comment: I think I found my problem. The above test wasn't working because I have duplicates in my original table. Original is old, without rules obviously. So I was deleting 1 to test, but that 1 had a duplicate/ :(